# How can I put a text with upward stretch at the bottom of the page?

Tags: jasper-reports

I need to put a dynamic disclaimer on the last page. The goal is to have it near the bottom of the page (I can put it in the footer if that helps) and grow / stretch *upwards*.

I tried:

```
<summary>
    <band height="250" splitType="Stretch">
        <rectangle>
            <reportElement mode="Transparent" x="1" y="1" width="736" height="248" forecolor="#000000" uuid="eab6a45c-8a83-414b-b6d2-89ca9320f533">
            </reportElement>
            <graphicElement>
                <pen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Dotted" lineColor="#FF8080"/>
            </graphicElement>
        </rectangle>
        <textField textAdjust="StretchHeight">
            <reportElement positionType="FixRelativeToBottom" key="" mode="Opaque" x="0" y="220" width="738" height="13" forecolor="#000066" backcolor="#F5F5F5" uuid="c169a12b-718a-431e-81c1-33731dc633ee">
            </reportElement>
            <textElement verticalAlignment="Bottom">
                <paragraph leftIndent="10" rightIndent="10" spacingBefore="7" spacingAfter="7"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression>"Footer\n\nSecond paragraph.\n\nThird paragraph."</textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
    </band>
</summary>
```

but the testfield still stretches downwards; there will either be a second page or the text will be cut off. I was expecting `positionType="FixRelativeToBottom"` to preserve the bottom coordinate and shrink the Y coordinate of the result.

Is there a trick how I can achieve this?

Requirements:

- 1-3 paragraphs of text in different languages (so no way to tell in advance how high the text field will be). This prevents tricks like 9 fields where 8 are always invisible/ignored.
- Gray background around the disclaimer which should fit the text (so no rectangle in the background and then print text over it).
- If you print different versions of the disclaimer, the bottom edge of the background should align when you put the paper sheets on top of each other

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?

Comment: @tom_h Not yet. Looking at the code, I doubt this is possible. But I wanted to be sure.